# Xcode 7 cannot install to device

Tags: xcode, build, installation, xcode7

Throws unknown error. I tried to install on my phone, factory reset phone, and a third phone, all give the same error:

It's difficult to understand what is actually the problem. Several other stack overflow questions had the same error message, but different output in the device log not related to mine.

Any ideas? It has been building and installing fine for months and all of a sudden..

```
May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone installd[2221] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/Corpsboard.app" type Developer (LSInstallType = (null)) requested by streaming_zip_conduit (pid 2245)
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone installd[2221] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.justin.corpboard; Version=0.4, ShortVersion=0.4>
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone profiled[1852] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone profiled[1852] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Updating MIS trust...
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone securityd[105] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone securityd[105] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone installd[2221] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone installd[2221] <Error>: MIS: unrecognized status -67049 from codesigning library
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone installd[2221] <Notice>: MIS: Could not copy code signature (error 0xe8008001).
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone installd[2221] <Error>: 0x16e087000 +[MICodeSigningVerifier _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:]: 142: Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.8MW6iG/extracted/Corpsboard.app/Frameworks/AFDateHelper.framework : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone installd[2221] <Error>: 0x16e087000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Verification stage failed
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[2245] <Error>: 0x16e2d3000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke222: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.8MW6iG/extracted/Corpsboard.app/Frameworks/AFDateHelper.framework : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)" UserInfo={LibMISErrorNumber=-402620415, LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, SourceFileLine=142, FunctionName=+[MICodeSigningVerifier _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:], NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.8MW6iG/extracted/Corpsboard.app/Frameworks/AFDateHelper.framework : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)}
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[2245] <Warning>: __dispatch_source_read_socket_block_invoke:299: Failed to install application at file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/Corpsboard.app/ : Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={Error=ApplicationVerificationFailed, ErrorDetail=-402620415, ErrorDescription=Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.8MW6iG/extracted/Corpsboard.app/Frameworks/AFDateHelper.framework : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)}
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone iaptransportd[81] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
            "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x146e2e280> com.justin.corpboard <(null) *Not found in database*>"
        )
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone UserEventAgent[26] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
            "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x135f165f0> com.justin.corpboard <(null) *Not found in database*>"
        )
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone bulletindistributord[65] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
            "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x14c5870f0> com.justin.corpboard <(null) *Not found in database*>"
        )
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone BTServer[1014] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
            "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x13dd59780> com.justin.corpboard <(null) *Not found in database*>"
        )
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone apsd[107] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
            "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x14fdca7b0> com.justin.corpboard <(null) *Not found in database*>"
        )
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone homed[149] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
            "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x13dd9be80> com.justin.corpboard <(null) *Not found in database*>"
        )
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone atc[43] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
            "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x15e741cf0> com.justin.corpboard <(null) *Not found in database*>"
        )
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone SpringBoard[63] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
            "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x1286a1740> com.justin.corpboard <(null) *Not found in database*>"
        )
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone nsurlsessiond[131] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
            "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x160009c40> com.justin.corpboard <(null) *Not found in database*>"
        )
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone itunesstored[116] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
            "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x12e83f560> com.justin.corpboard <(null) *Not found in database*>"
        )
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone profiled[1852] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
            "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x13f55a2f0> com.justin.corpboard <(null) *Not found in database*>"
        )
    May 19 21:52:36 Isaias-iPhone passd[1782] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
            "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x13cd69d60> com.justin.corpboard <(null) *Not found in database*>"
        )
    May 19 21:52:37 Isaias-iPhone securityd[105] <Error>:  SOSPeerCoderSendMessageIfNeeded 0mz5ovmoZQmcqr98JnIrTea6dT getCoder: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1032 "No coderData nor coder for peer: 0mz5ovmoZQmcqr98JnIrTea6dT" UserInfo={NSDescription=No coderData nor coder for peer: 0mz5ovmoZQmcqr98JnIrTea6dT}
    May 19 21:52:37 Isaias-iPhone securityd[105] <Error>:  __SOSCCProcessSyncWithAllPeers_Server_block_invoke sync with all peers failed: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1032 "No coderData nor coder for peer: 0mz5ovmoZQmcqr98JnIrTea6dT" UserInfo={NSDescription=No coderData nor coder for peer: 0mz5ovmoZQmcqr98JnIrTea6dT}
    May 19 21:52:37 Isaias-iPhone CloudKeychainProxy[197] <Error>:  __39-[UbiqitousKVSProxy doSyncWithAllPeers]_block_invoke_2 <UBK-s-pCS--> syncWithAllPeers (null), rescheduling timerre
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being Cocoapod related, though I don't understand why. 
In the device output log, I found a mention of 'AFDateHelper', which is a pod I use. After removing the pod, then reinstalling the pod, it started building to the device.

The pod hadn't been updated or changed since initially being installed, so not sure why it stopped.

Maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with RealmSwift in XCode 8 / iOS9/10
"Unknown Error" "An unknown error has occurred"

- Open Console
- Click on iOS device
- Searched for
- - "An unknown error has
    occurred" or "Failed to install application"

Found errors

```
"LaunchServices" 
"Apps Failed be installed"  //should be 'to be'
"Not found in database"
```

Scroll up 
 - found error related to a
   cocoapods framework

```
__dispatch_source_read_socket_block_invoke:299: Failed to install application at file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/app_p.app/ : Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={Error=ApplicationVerificationFailed, ErrorDetail=-402620415, ErrorDescription=Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.qjw4QY/extracted/app_p.app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)}
```

Related to RealmSwift.framework

Found old issue which recommended cleaning cache for just those pods:

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3473

so I ran this:

```
pod cache clean Realm
pod cache clean RealmSwift
pod install --verbose
```

- I also erased project from DerivedData
- I deleted the app of the iOS device if already on it to force clean install rather than upgrade.

App installed ok from XCode 8 to 2 devices one running iOS 10 and other iOS 9.

Note the Realm forum said to also remove all Pods and re-add

```
pod cache clean Realm
pod cache clean RealmSwift
pod deintegrate || rm -rf Pods
pod install --verbose
```

but I did this before and it messed up my git repo.

When I opened the folder with the project in SourceTree Git client the url to the repo was pointing to cocoapods spec project not the repo for my project.

But I fixed the error without pod deintegrate so I cant confirm if this is still and issue.